# How to fix "Instance member 'coordinate' cannot be used on type 'MKMapPoint'" error in Swift 5.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

I am using Apple’s [Footprint: Indoor Positioning with Core Location sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/footprint/Introduction/Intro.html) to build a mobile application. This code is in Swift 3.0, and I am converting it to Swift 5.0 syntax. 
When I run this Swift 3.0 code,

```
coordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(boundingMapRect.getCenter())
```

I get this error.

> *“MKCoordinateForMapPoint' has been replaced by property 'MKMapPoint.coordinate'”*

When I changed the syntax to

```
coordinate = MKMapPoint.coordinate (boundingMapRect.getCenter())
```

I get this error message

> *“Instance member 'coordinate' cannot be used on type 'MKMapPoint'”*

How can I get this line of code to run?

Comment: Perhaps `coordinate = MKMapPoint(boundingMapRect.getCenter()).coordinate`

Comment: or simply `coordinate = boundingMapRect.getCenter().coordinate`

Comment: Your second suggestion worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple defined `getCenter()` in an extension of `MKMapRect`:

```
extension MKMapRect {
    /**
        - returns: The point at the center of the rectangle.
        - parameter rect: A rectangle.
    */
    func getCenter() -> MKMapPoint {
        return MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMidX(self), MKMapRectGetMidY(self))
        // now return MKMapPoint(x: self.midX, y: self.midY)
    }
}
```

Since `getCenter()` returns a `MKMapPoint`, you simply need to access its `coordinate` property:

```
coordinate = boundingMapRect.getCenter().coordinate
```